# add multiple rows in sql using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know the simple method of adding one row into sql database using netbeans.

Here is that method:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zeeshan",
                                              "root","sHaNi97426");
Statement stmt = (Statement)conn.createStatement();
String insert = "INSERT INTO clients VALUES('"+hostname+"');";
stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
```

Now, I want to add multiple rows in sql database. For example, in the code given below:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((s.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print(s.readLine()); 
}
```

I want to add each line in sql till `s.readLine()` becomes `null`.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it incorrectly! With your current code you'll end up missing alternate lines as you are calling `readLine()` twice but only outputting it the first time.

Also, if you want to insert multiple rows in your DB then you should be looking at a `Batch`.

Here is the JAVA Doc of `addBatch()`:

> Adds the given SQL command to the current list of commands for this Statement object. The commands in this list can be executed as a batch by calling the method executeBatch.

You should be doing something like this:

```
String input = null;
while ((input = s.readLine()) != null) {
    stmt.addBatch(input); 
}
```

Here is how you can execute the Batch:

```
int[] result = stmt.executeBatch();
```